# flash player and mysql

Tags: mysql, flash, actionscript, video, host

i want to know if it is possible to play a video via flash player, when the video is located on different server's mysql. for example:

i want to play video on server2.com which(video) is located in server1.com mysql

Comment: Your video is stored in a database?!

Comment: yes (please don't recomend to save it on file system),
can i have php file fetch it and then have the php file be the file in the flash's object tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need a middle-man here, that retrieves the video from the database and serves it.
as far as i know, flash does not have connectors to mysql (maybe AIR does).
maybe a thin server on PHP can do the job easily.

**Update:**
[PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/)

Comment: what if i create php file and retrieve .flv as xml file and than actionscript opens it and playes it. is it possible?

Comment: you could have the php file deliver the file in binary form as well. actionscript will retrieve the file through an HTTPService instance and you're set.

Comment: can you give me a link where i can find some info, tutorial, or something that will help to do this